# Neo4j Database error General Unknown Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

```
Load csv with headers from "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pyWY81bKzcCF7T-i_-MyhY2kJ4Z8NYP8" as row
with row
return row
```

this is my code I am trying to access the csv file with 1 million records from my drive using load csv

It is giving me following error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: At https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pyWY81bKzcCF7T-i_-MyhY2kJ4Z8NYP8 @ position 1750 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: 'docs-fwds":'
```

I am not getting the issue 
can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pyWY81bKzcCF7T-i_-MyhY2kJ4Z8NYP8` not returning file because of its size

Comment: Note that when you do get this to point at your CSV, you'll want to use [USING PERIODIC COMMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) when doing your load so it batches the load process, that should avoiding blowing the heap trying to load the entire file in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL` you entered is not the actual path of the file but the link to a page which opens the file from google drive. **So the link you provided points to the HTML page and not the CSV file.**

If you want actual URL to the file try to download it and copy the URL that appears in the new tab.

You can change your query as follows(updated with actual URL):

```
Load csv with headers from "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pyWY81bKzcCF7T-i_-MyhY2kJ4Z8NYP8" as row
with row
return row
```

> Don't return a row if the file is large, the browser will become
>   unresponsive.